# ElementTree Unicode Encode/Decode Error

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, elementtree

For a project I'm supposed to enhance some XML and store it in a file. The problem I encountered is that I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bart\Dropbox\Studie\2013-2014\BSc-KI\cite_parser\parser.py", line 193, in parse_references
    outputXML = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1126, in tostring
    ElementTree(element).write(file, encoding, method=method)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 820, in write
    serialize(write, self._root, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 939, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 939, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 939, in _serialize_xml
    _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
 ECLI:NL:RVS:2012:BY1564
 File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 937, in _serialize_xml
    write(_escape_cdata(text, encoding))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1073, in _escape_cdata
    return text.encode(encoding, "xmlcharrefreplace")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 80: ordinal not in range(128)
```

That error was generated by:

```
outputXML = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml')
```

When looking for a solution to this problem i found several suggestions saying I should add `.decode('utf-8')` to the function but that results in an Encoding error (first it was decoding) from the write function so that doesn't work...

The encoding error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Bart\Dropbox\Studie\2013-2014\BSc-KI\cite_parser\parser.py", line 197, in parse_references
    myfile.write(outputXML)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xeb' in position 13559: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It is generated by the following code:

```
outputXML = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml').decode('utf-8')
```

Source (or at least the relevant parts):

```
# URL encodes the parameters
encoded_parameters = urllib.urlencode({'id':ecli})

# Opens XML file
feed = urllib2.urlopen("http://data.rechtspraak.nl/uitspraken/content?"+encoded_parameters, timeout = 3)

# Parses the XML
ecliFile = ET.parse(feed)

# Fetches root element of current tree
root = ecliFile.getroot()

# Write the XML to a file without any extra indents or newlines
outputXML = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml')

# Write the XML to the file
with open(file, "w") as myfile:
    myfile.write(outputXML)
```

And last but not least an URL to an XML sample: [http://data.rechtspraak.nl/uitspraken/content?id=ECLI:NL:RVS:2012:BY1542](http://data.rechtspraak.nl/uitspraken/content?id=ECLI%3aNL%3aRVS:2012%3aBY1542)

Comment: What is the full traceback of the exception? It's not ElementTree itself that triggers that, I'd wager.

Comment: I just added the full tracebacks for both exceptions :)

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, not with Python 2.7.6 at any rate.

Comment: The `UnicodeDecodeError` is out of place; it implies that there is *byte string data* in the tree, instead of the expected Unicode. Have you manipulated the tree, added elements? If so, make sure you add *Unicode strings*, not byte strings.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, think i found the problem, it was indeed the result of adding none unicode elements to the tree. Should i delete this question?

Comment: I've made it an answer instead; it could be helpful to others that run into this exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception is caused by a byte string value.

`text` in the traceback is supposed to be a unicode value, but if it is a plain byte string, Python will implicitly first decode it (with the ASCII codec) to Unicode just so you can then *encode* it again.

It is that *decoding* that fails.

Because you didn't actually show us what you insert into the XML tree, it is hard to tell you what to fix, other than to make sure you always use Unicode values when inserting text.

Demo:

```
>>> root.attrib['oops'] = u'Data with non-ASCII codepoints \u2014 (em dash)'.encode('utf8')
>>> ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1126, in tostring
    ElementTree(element).write(file, encoding, method=method)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 820, in write
    serialize(write, self._root, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 932, in _serialize_xml
    v = _escape_attrib(v, encoding)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1090, in _escape_attrib
    return text.encode(encoding, "xmlcharrefreplace")
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> root.attrib['oops'] = u'Data with non-ASCII codepoints \u2014 (em dash)'
>>> ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml')
'<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'utf8\'?> ...'
```

Setting a bytestring attribute, containing bytes outside the ASCII range, triggers the excetpion; using a unicode value instead ensured the result could be produced.